# SQL Update loop returning last value to all records?

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, sql-update

Trying to update the price daily of my table for a certain lot of sales every day.

The print all return the correct 'PLU' and counter but they are all updating to the same result?

```
declare @RowCount int
declare @Starter int
declare @tempPLU varchar(50)

Set @RowCount = (Select count(@@ROWCOUNT) from Filemaker.dbo.BatchAverageSales 
                 where BatchID = 2404)
set @Starter = 0

while (@Starter < @RowCount)
begin 
    set @tempPLU = (select top(1) Filemaker.dbo.BatchAverageSales.PLU 
                    from Filemaker.dbo.BatchAverageSales 
                    where Filemaker.dbo.BatchAverageSales.RRP is null)

    update F
    set F.RRP = final.RRP
    from Filemaker.DBO.BatchAverageSales as F 
    cross join
        (select product.fldProductPrice as RRP from PRODUCT) final
    inner join Product on F.PLU = product.fldProductCode
    where f.PLU = @tempPLU

    print(@tempPLU)
    print(@starter)

    set @Starter = @Starter + 1
end
```

SQL Print pane

```
(1 row affected)
0321
0

(1 row affected)
0504
1

(1 row affected)
0511
2

(1 row affected)
0512
3

(1 row affected)
0516
4

(1 row affected)
0526
5

(1 row affected)
0568
6

(1 row affected)
1072
7

(1 row affected)
2525
8

(1 row affected)
2565
9

(1 row affected)
3505
10

(1 row affected)
3525
11

(1 row affected)
4521
12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is strange code....

```
  update F
set F.RRP = final.RRP
from Filemaker.DBO.BatchAverageSales as F 
cross join
    (select product.fldProductPrice as RRP from PRODUCT) final
```

final.RRP is the same on every step in your loop and ( I think ) is equal fldProductPrice in last record of Product table.

May be it should be like this

```
      update F
set F.RRP = final.RRP
from Filemaker.DBO.BatchAverageSales as F 
cross join
    (select product.fldProductPrice as RRP from PRODUCT 
      where fldProductCode = F.PLU ) final
```

Or ( on my taste ) is more short solution

```
declare @BatchID int = 2404
update BAS 
set RRP = P.fldProductPrice
from Filemaker.dbo.BatchAverageSales BAS
join  Product P on F.PLU = P.fldProductCode
where BAS.BatchID = @BatchID
```

Comment: Hi DiamSUN, First solution set all as the first price, second solution works. Thanks heaps mate.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are storing value into @tempPLU and then using it to update. Instead of why you are not using select query directly as a subquery into select statement as below.

```
    declare @RowCount int
    declare @Starter int
    declare @tempPLU varchar(50)
    Set @RowCount = (Select count(@@ROWCOUNT) from Filemaker.dbo.BatchAverageSales where BatchID = 2404)
    set @Starter = 0

    while (@Starter < @RowCount)
    Begin 
    update F
    set F.RRP = final.RRP
    from Filemaker.DBO.BatchAverageSales as F cross join
        (select product.fldProductPrice as RRP from PRODUCT) final
    inner join Product on F.PLU = product.fldProductCode
    where f.PLU = (select top(1)Filemaker.dbo.BatchAverageSales.PLU from Filemaker.dbo.BatchAverageSales where Filemaker.dbo.BatchAverageSales.RRP is NULL )
    print(@starter)
    set @Starter = @Starter + 1

    end
```

Comment: HI Mak, i added this for testing, i should of cleaned up before posting, same result